# django allow_tags not working in changeview in sometimes

Tags: python, django

Django version:1.9.2
python version:2.7.5
my model:

```
class User(models.Model):
    headimgurl = models.CharField(verbose_name=u"icon", default=None, null=True, max_length=512, blank=True)
    def head_img(self):
        default_img_url = "http://mat1.gtimg.com/bbs/life-admin/activity/assets/logo.png"
        html = u"<img style=\"height:50px; width:50px;\" src=\"%s\"/>" % (self.headimgurl or default_img_url)
        return html
    head_img.allow_tags = True
    head_img.short_description = u"icon"
```

my admin:

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = (
        ('head_img', 'headimgurl',),
    )
    readonly_fields = ("head_img", )
    list_display = ('head_img', )

    enter code here
```

I run the program and visit the website, all the icon show in list view, but some icon not show in change view.
[image]
All the icons show in list view.
In change view the mokey icon was shown:
[image]
[image]
But the cartoon boy icon not shown in change view:
[image]
[image]
What is the problem? Why some icon shown in change view but others not shown?